# mvn test command not running tests in a Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, maven, junit

This is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ricardo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdh</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cdh</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <azure.version>2.2.0</azure.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.44</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.44</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-eventhubs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>local</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>test</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn test` this is the output and none of the test run. However every test work as expected using the IDE Intellij.

```
[INFO] Building cdh 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ cdh ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/ricardochampa/mypath/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ cdh ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ cdh ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 140 source files to /Users/mypath/cdh-back/target/classes
[INFO] /Users/mypath/cdh-back/src/main/java/com/ricardo/cdh/mappers/OrdersMapper.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /Users/mypath/cdh-back/src/main/java/com/ricardo/cdh/mappers/OrdersMapper.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ cdh ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/mypath/cdh-back/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ cdh ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to /Users/mypath/cdh-back/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ cdh ---
[INFO] 


[INFO] -------------------------< com.ricardo:cdh >--------------------------
[INFO] Building cdh 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ cdh ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ cdh ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ cdh ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/mypath/cdh-back/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ cdh ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ cdh ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.484 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-30T22:18:05+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## UPDATE

I've just try with the following pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And I tried this as well.

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>customWildcardPattern</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this...

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this...

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

None of them works :(

The project structure.

[image]

An example of test class: ProductsServiceTest

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProductsServiceTest {
    @Mock ProductsRepository productsRepository;
    @Mock ResourceService resourceService;
    @Autowired @InjectMocks ProductsService service;
    private ProductsEntity productsEntity = new ProductsEntity();
    private final String stubSearchText = "search this text with results";
    private final String stubSearchTextNoResults = "search this text without results";
    private final String notFoundStubID = "ID NOT EXISTS";
    private final String stubID = "id";
    private final String stubName = "name";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        productsEntity.setId(stubID);
        productsEntity.setName(stubName);
        when(productsRepository.findById(stubID)).thenReturn(Optional.of(productsEntity));
        when(productsRepository.findById(notFoundStubID)).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        doNothing().when(resourceService).changeResourceStatus(any(String.class), any(String.class));
        List<ProductsEntity> productsEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
        productsEntityList.add(productsEntity);
        when(productsRepository.searchProducts(stubSearchText)).thenReturn(productsEntityList);
    }
    @Test
    public void whenGetProduct() throws CdhException {
        ProductsDto productsDto = service.getProduct(stubID);
        assertEquals(productsDto.getId(), stubID);
        assertEquals(productsDto.getName(), stubName);
    }
    @Test
    public void whenGetProductNotExist() {
        assertThatThrownBy(() -> service.getProduct(notFoundStubID)).isInstanceOf(CdhException.class);
    }
    @Test
    public void whenCreateProduct() {
        ProductsDto dto = new ProductsDto();
        dto.setId("fake id");
        dto.setIdResource("fake id resource");
        service.createProduct(dto);
        verify(service.productsRepository).save(any(ProductsEntity.class));
    }
    @Test
    public void whenDeleteProduct() throws CdhException {
        service.deleteProduct(stubID);
        verify(service.productsRepository).save(any(ProductsEntity.class));
    }

}
```

Comment: If the solution provided by M.mas works then kudos!! Else it would be better if you post your test package structure and also the Test class where the junit is written

Comment: Please add one of those test class.

Comment: Done. Added one test class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally fix it.
My problems was JUnit4, according to docs https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html I should add the plugin like this.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

**1. First potential root cause : Test class naming**

Make sure that your test class name matchs one of those default Maven Surefire plugin patterns:

1. Test*.java
2. *Test.java
3. *Tests.java
4. *TestCase.java

If you need to customize it, you need to add :

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>TO_BE_REPLACED_BY_YOUR_CUSTOM_WILDCARD_PATTERN</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

**###UPDATE####:**

**2.  Second potential root cause that may lead to not executing test is the exclusion part in your `spring-boot-starter-test`**

Replace:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

by:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I added the dependency but still the tests are not running. All my test clases ends with Test.java

Answer (score 1):

maven surefire plugin is missing in your pom.xml.

Comment: Spring-boot should bring this plugin for you.
Have a look at the log, you'll see clearly : 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ cdh ---

Comment: I've just added the plugin 2.22.2 but still the same behaviour. The test clases are not running. All my test clases ends with Test.java

Comment: Try adding junit-jupiter-engine and junit-jupiter-api dependencies with scope test

Comment: https://youtu.be/EROuIf2Ac_I you can refer to this link as well

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to understand the test engines that Spring uses.

In my case, I coded API tests with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, which is under JUnit4, which runs with `junit-vintage-engine`.

But the unit tests are coded with JUnit Jupiter, which is under JUnit5, which runs with `junit-jupiter-engine`.

The default engine of SpringBoot is the `junit-jupiter-engine`. So we have to tell to Spring that we also want to use `junit-vintage-engine`.

We can simply add the dependency in our pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Or, if we want to use maven-surefire, we can add the dependency inside the plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and in my case I somehow ended up with a combination of Junit 5 and Junit 4 in my application context. Spring boot starter test was scanning for Junit 5 tests and some of my legacy tests were annotated with Junit 4. Once I brought the legacy tests up to Junit 5 they were found when running the maven test lifecycle event. Both types of tests ran fine when running them each manually.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to annotate your test methods with `@Test`:
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; // <-- or whatever you are using..

```
public class SomeTest {
  ...

  @Test // <----
  public void testSomething() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```